# Can I bulk load documents with inline attachments to Cloudant?

Tags: cloudant

I want to bulk load a set of documents into a Cloudant DB.  Cloudant provides a REST endpoint for this, _bulk_docs.  But some of the documents I want to load contain attachments.  If I were creating these documents individually, I could create the attachment along with the document by including it as an inline attachment.  But it's not clear whether the _bulk_docs endpoint supports documents with inline attachments.  The documentation does not say one way or the other, and my own attempts are so far unsuccessful.

Can someone please give an authoritative answer on whether the _bulk_docs endpoint of Cloudant supports docs with inline attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _bulk_docs endpoint does support docs with inline attachments.

I finally got this to work.  My earlier attempts failed due to an unrelated problem.  I was able to successfully bulk load 51 documents, 14 of which have inline attachments.